# Radio button checked but not showing as checked

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, datatables-1.10

My table consists of 15 records which divided in 2 pages, however, those radio buttons in first page will not be checked as shown in image below.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6Ia9.jpg)

Here the code used in view page:

```
<?php foreach($rights->result() as $row){
      echo "<label class='radio-inline'><input type='radio' name='rightRBtn[".$perm_id."]' value='$row->id'".(($row->id == $right_id) ? " checked='checked'":'')." />" . $row->description."</label>";     
}?>
```

Browser source view shows the radio button box is actually checked too.

`<td><label class='radio-inline'><input type='radio' name='rightRBtn[22]' value='0' checked='checked' />none</label><label class='radio-inline'><input type='radio' name='rightRBtn[22]' value='1' />view</label>                                    </td>`

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Yes, but the output still the same.

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#51 (2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "0" ["description"]=> string(4) "none" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#52 (2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["description"]=> string(4) "view" } }  This is $right_id --> 1

Comment: but `$row->id` equals to `$right_id`

Comment: Will it be a bootstrap or datatables problem? Because I tried with pure html code and the radio button did not checked either.

Comment: No, it's run on local.

Comment: it's ok, thank you for helping.

Answer (score 3):

Simplify `foreach()` loop code by apply simple `if-else` and save yourself from some unnecessary quotes adjustment.

```
<?php foreach($rights->result() as $row){
  if($row->id == $right_id){
    echo "<label class='radio-inline'><input type='radio' name='rightRBtn[".$perm_id."]' value='$row->id' checked/>" . $row->description ."</label>"; 
  }else{
    echo "<label class='radio-inline'><input type='radio' name='rightRBtn[".$perm_id."]' value='$row->id'/>" . $row->description ."</label>"; 
  }   
}
?>
```

***At my local end it's working:-***

Code i used:-https://prnt.sc/ht9mzb  (i just use json_decode and json_encode to make it stdclassobject array as you have)

output:-https://prnt.sc/ht9m1n

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this issue is to remove the `responsive: true`

```
$('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
//            responsive: true 
});
```